# Why does SqlConnection forget the database type

Tags: c#, .net, sqlconnection

I recently posted (and promptly deleted, when I decided the question was irrelevant to the actual problem) a question about SqlConnection losing its Database information when the scope of "ChangeDatabase" ends.  Example:

```
    //Other code...
    dbConn = new SqlConnection(dbConnBuilder.ConnectionString);
    dbConn.Open();
    dbConn.ChangeDatabase(currentDatabase);
    dbConn.Close();
}
```

My questions:

1. Is it considered bad practice to hold onto a `SqlConnection` object and open and close it whenever you need it when you'll only ever have ONE connection of a given type?
2. Why does `dbConn.Database` *not* remember `currentDatabase` after ChangeDatabase (a *method* not a variable) 'Goes out of scope'? (Heck, I didn't know methods like `ChangeDatabase` could know about scope).

My connection string was:

```
Data Source=server.name.com;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password
```

Thanks guys, let me know if I can give you more information, still learning to use S.O.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `Close()` completely destroys the object, so you should not be reading any of its properties after.

In fact, there should even *be* an "after" because you shouldn't be calling `Close()`. Instead, instantiate the connection in a `using` block, so that it'll call `Dispose()`, which does the same thing as `Close()`, but is guaranteed to do so no matter how you leave the block.

Comment: So re-construction is truly the only way to go with this? (Keeping a SqlConnection around is a bad way to go?)

Comment: Correct. You gain nothing from keeping it around because there's an underlying connection pool, anyhow.

Comment: The rule of thumb -- with a few sensible exceptions -- is to use `using` for anything that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Cpfohl: I'm confused by your question.  What is the point of keeping around a `SqlConnection` object if the underlying connection has already been `Close()` d?  If you want to implement your own connection pooling (which is a bad idea for other reasons), you would want to keep *open* connections around, right?  Or are you trying to do something different?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful if you include the database in the connection string, just so you can avoid changing database each time.

Comment: @Daniel, it was a lack of understanding of Close() (Imho, "Close()" is a bad name for something that destroys something, when you open or close a door it remains a connection between two rooms despite being closed. When you close an account it doesn't cease being an account, and it can typically be re-opened, etc. etc.)

Comment: @Cpfohl: You're not wrong. It would have been just fine if they'd left us with just `Dispose`.

Comment: Fwiw: It would totally suck if every time you closed a door it destroyed the connection between rooms entirely.

Answer (score 0):

So just make sure to call changedatabase every time you need to execute a statement :-)

Comment: Thanks :-).  That would work except I was hoping to abstract that away so I could just say: get the database and use it, not get, set up, then use it.